# Just installed Rails 6 and am getting an odd error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

installed ruby 2.6.4 and rails 6.0.0 using rbenv on a mac running Mojave 10.14.6 to evaluate upgrading a legacy app. rails -v returns `
    Rails 6 requires Ruby 2.5.0 or newer.

```
You're running
  ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]

Please upgrade to Ruby 2.5.0 or newer to continue.`
```

however ruby -v returns `ruby 2.6.4p104 (2019-08-28 revision 67798) [x86_64-darwin18]`

I currently have the following versions of ruby installed

ruby-2.2.6
   ruby-2.3.8
 * ruby-2.6.4

which ruby returns

/Users/jerryzornes/.rubies/ruby-2.6.4/bin/ruby

and my bundler version is 2.0.2

So I have no idea as to what's going on.

Comment: Are you still needing help with this?

Answer (score 0):

In the root folder of your Rails app make sure you have a file named `.ruby-version` that contains the text `ruby-2.6.4`. This is used by rbenv to make sure the right version of ruby is used.

You can also run `which ruby` to see where it is loading ruby from. If this isn't running from `/Users/jerryzornes/.rubies/...`, then the issue is with your rbenv install. I would check you path variable to make sure it has the rbenv shims in place, ie looks like `~/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`

Comment: I have a .ruby-version file and like my original post says which ruby returns the ruby 2.6.4

Comment: Can you run/copy+paste the results`rbenv versions` from the root of your project. If you run `bundle exec rails -v` does it work correctly?